casdoor PHP SDK integration with Laravel
I am new with casdoor or whole SSO concept, I want to integrate casdoor PHP SDK with Laravel for creating API for create account, verify the token, password reset and account update.Can someone point me/guide me to any example with laravel that will be helpful Thanks!
I went through the official SDK documentation but I am not able to understand here is the link
"https://github.com/casdoor/casdoor-php-sdk" and "https://casdoor.org/docs/how-to-connect/sdk"
